# memory leaks when opening sqlite database in iOS?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, memory-management, memory-leaks

I have been getting constant memory leak at this line

```
> if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &databaseHandle) != SQLITE_OK)
```

. What could be the reason ?? I have even closed the database after opening it . But its of no avail.

My whole method is

> 

```
-(void)copyCustomDatabase{
    /** done - @todo Copy db file from app resources */
    @try {
        NGMobileCaptureSingleton * singleton = [NGMobileCaptureSingleton getSharedInstance]; 
        NSString *documentsDirectory = [singleton getAppDocumentDirectory];
        NSString *apkIdStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [NGMobileCaptureSingleton getSharedInstance].apkId];
        NSString *databaseName = [[[[@"ngcapcust_" stringByAppendingString:apkIdStr] stringByAppendingString:@"_"] stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", formId]] stringByAppendingString:@".db"];
            NSString *databasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
//          NSLog(@"copyCustomDatabase Custom Database Path %@", databasePath);
            bool databaseAlreadyExists = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];
            if (!databaseAlreadyExists)
            {
                NSError *error;
                NSFileManager *fileManager = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] init];
                NSString *srcPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath]  stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName];
                [fileManager copyItemAtPath:srcPath toPath:databasePath error:&error];   
            }                
            if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &databaseHandle) != SQLITE_OK)
                {              
                        [self closeDatabase];                            
                        NSLog(@"NGDefaultCustomHelper copyCustomDatabase Error in creating database handle");
        //            } else {
        //                NSLog(@"NGDefaultCustomHelper copyCustomDatabase Database handle created successfully");          
     }   
        } @catch (NSException *exception) {
            NSLog(@"NGDefaultCustomHelper copyCustomDatabase exception : %@", exception);
        } 
    }

- (void)closeDatabase
 {
    sqlite3_close(databaseHandle);

    databaseHandle = NULL;

    tableMap = NULL;

    tableIdMap = NULL;
}
```

Comment: Do you ever close the database later?

Comment: 1) Are you using ARC ?
2) It seems pretty weird, you check that data is open or not. If not open you are trying to close !!! What happens if database is open ?

Comment: @MidhunMP Yes I am using ARC , Nothing happens when db is open , it is just there to notify wether query was executed successfully or not

Comment: I have been getting hundreds of memory leaks malloc . all pointing on the line i mentioned on my question

Comment: When are the leaks being detected?  Obviously you must wait until your app has finished using the DB and closed it.  (And add an NSLog to your close routine to make sure it's getting executed.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &databaseHandle)` returns `databaseHandle`, which ([according to the docs](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/open.html)) "**Whether or not an error occurs when it is opened, resources associated with the database connection handle** should be released by passing it to `sqlite3_close()` when it is no longer required".

Comment: I have closed by calling the closedatabase method. still no avail

Comment: Actually not. You do it only if you could open the database successfully. But the docs say "Whether or not an error occurs when it is opened, resources associated with the database connection handle should be released by passing it to sqlite3_close() when it is no longer required."

Comment: So I should close it no matter what is the result of the option ?

Comment: Yes, so the docs say.

Comment: Thank you so much !!It works . All leaks are taken care of.

Comment: Glad that I could help you!

Answer (score 0):

The reason is you don't close the database with [`sqlite_close()`](http://www.sqlite.org/c_interface.html).

Comment: I am using ARC and in my close database method , I am closing the database.    
- (void)closeDatabase{
    sqlite3_close(databaseHandle);
    databaseHandle = NULL;
    tableMap = NULL;
    tableIdMap = NULL;
//    NSLog(@"NGDefaultCustomHelper closeDatabase");
}

Answer (score 0):

U forgot to add sqlite_close()